# How to make document names to be clickable hyperlinks?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a search engine that indexes a collection of files on my hard drive. I have a script that takes a query `query = raw_input()` and outputs a set of file names.

I want the file names to be clickable hyperlinks that open the file when the user clicks on them.

How do I do this? My interface (if this requires an interface) would just be a search box and an output box.

This appears to be possible in [`MATLAB`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2007/07/09/printing-hyperlinks-to-the-command-window).

Also, if there's an IDE that allows this, that would be acceptable (but not preferable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import webbrowser

...

self.entryfield = Entry(self.frame)

...
mybutton = Button(self.frame, text="Open site",
command= lambda: webbrowser.open(self.entryfield.get()))
```

If the user enters `http://www.stackoverflow.com` into the `self.entryfield` and clicks `mybutton`, it'll open a browser and go to SO.

See [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/webbrowser.html).

Comment: Thanks--this may be a stupid question, but I want to navigate to a file on my local drive, not a website. Can I still use this?

Comment: Yes, it should work. To test it, open a Python shell and try `import webbrowser`, `webbrowser.open(file)`, where `file` is the path to a file on your local machine. You can also try `import os` and then `os.system(file)`, which sends the string in `file` to your system's command line shell.

Comment: With os.system(file) I get `sh: /Users/Desktop/networks/RecordFull.txt: Permission denied
32256`

Comment: That looks like some flavor of Unix. Since it's a permissions error, maybe you need to prepend `sudo ` to the string?

Comment: I've already used sudo...anyway, when I try it on a file with full permissions, it enters vim. I want the file to be opened in textedit.

Comment: Then perhaps `"sudo textedit " + file`? It's simply executing the string you pass it with the command line. If you'd rather it do whatever your system's web browser would do to open a particular filetype, use `webbrowser` as originally suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73123/discussion-between-user99889-and-tigerhawkt3).

Answer (score 1):

I invit you to have a look at the pydoc module ...
in 
Python27/Lib/pydoc.py

The Pydoc GUI class gives a good idea of how to display and start a search engine. 
And in the case of Pydoc .. It manage the startup of the browser efficiently.

Additionnally but I did not look deeper in the detail of the source code.
The moduleScanner creates a complete HTML interface with hyperlinks that should answer the question.

in Pydoc you will find

```
def open(self, event=None, url=None):
    url = url or self.server.url
    try:
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open(url)
    except ImportError: # pre-webbrowser.py compatibility
        if sys.platform == 'win32':
            os.system('start "%s"' % url)
        else:
            rc = os.system('netscape -remote "openURL(%s)" &' % url)
            if rc: os.system('netscape "%s" &' % url)
```

If the Url is a document ("c:/tmp/mydoc.docx") the start command will start Microsoft Word according to the assoc and ftype windows commands

The complete code should be executed directly without webbrowser like :

```
def open(self, event=None, path=None, tool=None, options=None):
    if option:stroptions = '%s'%options
    else:     stroptions = ''
    if tool  :strtool = '"%s"'%tool
    else:     strtool = ''  #to let the system associates itself 
    if path  :strpath = '"%s"'%path
    else:     strpath = 'just_an_example.doc'
    try:
        if sys.platform == 'win32':
            os.system('start '+strpath)
        else:
            os.system(strtool+' '+stroptions+' '+strpath)
    except: 
        os.system(strtool+' '+stroptions+' '+strpath)
```

Comment: Could you explain briefly the reason? (I am just trying to make this website a better resource for everybody ;)

Comment: My answer was written to give an idea and enhance the debat TigerhawkT3 seems to continue